# Shopify randomly gives "not found" errors

Tags: shopify

I have a script that imports large volumes of products into a Shopify store. I have implemented sleeps throughout the program to prevent spamming the API server, as well as a method to prevent exceeding the Shopify API call limit.

Everything seems to be working fine, except sometimes Shopify randomly gives me a "`Not Found`" error when `POST`ing to `/admin/products.json`. My current work-around is to re-try creating the product  when Shopify returns "`Not Found`" for up to 5 times. Usually it succeeds the second or third attempt.

Why is this happening? It seems the Shopify API / API servers are very unreliable.

Answer (score 0):

The reason could be shopify api server or it could be a problem in the hosting where you have the script running. Maybe you can try to increase the sleep time to see if that helps. Also please check the api call limit documentation carefully again. https://help.shopify.com/api/guides/api-call-limit